# Represent the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and $x=2y$ as a vector-valued function.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, spheres

**Problem :** Represent the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and $x=2y$ as a vector-valued function.
*(Hint: Let $y=\cos t$)*

**My Attempt**
$$z^2 = 5- 4\cos^2t - \cos^2t = 5- 5\cos^2t$$

$$z = \sqrt{5(1-\cos^2t)} = \sin(t) \sqrt5$$

and that is where I am stuck. I cannot figure out whether I should use the positive or negative sign after taking the square root of $z$. Please let me know which one to choose and why.

Comment: The second equation is that of a plane, not a line.

Comment: A line intersects a sphere in at most two points, so the question becomes silly if it were a sphere and a line.  In this case, even though $z$ isn't in the equation, you're in three dimensional space, so $z$ can be any value, making this into a plane.

Comment: i get y'alls point, but I was trying to compare it to the logic of this one example on the textbook. intersection of a 3d object and a plane curve as well ( ill add picture on the post)

Comment: The page that you posted is likely copyrighted and it might not be appropriate to include it.

Comment: oh snap ill remove hehe. thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the work that you've shown, you've come up with two possible answers:

$$
\left(2\cos(t),\cos(t),\sqrt{5}\sin(t)\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(2\cos(t),\cos(t),-\sqrt{5}\sin(t)\right).
$$
both with a domain of $0\leq t<2\pi$.

Since both satisfy the given equations, both are correct.  But also notice that if you replace $t$ with $-t$ in the first parametric form, you get 
$$
\left(2\cos(-t),\cos(-t),\sqrt{5}\sin(-t)\right)=\left(2\cos(t),\cos(t),-\sqrt{5}\sin(t)\right).
$$

Therefore, the two parameterizations trace out *the same curve* just in different directions!

In general, there are many parameterizations for the same curve.  For example,
$$
\left(2\cos(20t),\cos(20t),\sqrt{5}\sin(20t)\right)
$$
with a domain of $0\leq 2<\frac{\pi}{10}$ is also a parameterization for the intersection.

Comment: wait so what is the correct one that my teacher  will mark correct?

Comment: Why must there be one correct answer?  I don't know what your teacher will do, but they're the same curve.

Comment: ahh I see, so the intersected line is so to speak like a circle. No matter which direction the trace goes it is the "same"